# Gradle - DependencySubstitution for Android App with a Library

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, dependency-management

I have an Android app project with separate android library module inside, that is published as a binary. I'd like to add an ability to switch the gradle between building a library from sources or using the published artifact. 
Android app depends on binary artifact by default :

`compile "com.example.konstantin.mylibrary:mylibrary:${mylibraryVersion}"`

Now I want my binary artifact to be replaced by the source code, so I add the following code in root build.gradle file :

```
configurations.all {
resolutionStrategy {
    dependencySubstitution {
        substitute module("com.example.konstantin.mylibrary:mylibrary:${mylibraryVersion}") with project(':mylibrary')
    }
}
```

However when I'm trying to build gradle is still taking the binary artifact. What is wrong here?

[here is the full source code](https://github.com/Kostik8/testMultiModule)

Also interesting is that if I move dependency substitution code to allprojects section or to application module build.gradle file, than gradle fails to build with the following message :

```
Error:Module version MyApplication:app:unspecified, configuration '_debugCompile' declares a dependency on configuration 'default' which is not declared in the module descriptor for MyApplication:mylibrary:unspecified
```

Comment: Seems like [this android plugin bug](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=189483) could be related to the problem

Answer (score 4):

Finally I've found a working solution. Somehow that works if I do it the other way round. Instead of substitute binary with project module

```
substitute module("com.example.konstantin.mylibrary:mylibrary:${mylibraryVersion}") with project(':mylibrary')
```

I can substitute project module with binary   :

```
substitute project(':mylibrary') with module("com.example.konstantin.mylibrary:mylibrary:${mylibraryVersion}")
```

And than the magic works. 
The full working code is available on [separate branch of an example repo](https://github.com/Kostik8/testMultiModule/tree/that_works)

However that's not an ideal solution, because I have to always link the project module in settings.gradle and can not build without checking it out.